# Seaborn PairGrid - how to add frames? (top and right spines)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I'm trying to change the style of sns PairGrid graph. Namely, I want to add a frame around each of the grid graphs. What one graph looks like right now:

[image: the graph now]

How I want it to look:

[image: the graph with the frame]

I've already spent a ton of time reading the documentation and searching the Internet, but I haven't found any suitable answer. Is it even possible with PairGrid?

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `despine=False` option of [`PairGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.html):

```
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
g = sns.PairGrid(penguins, despine=False)
g.map(sns.scatterplot)
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, mozway! It helped! I can't imagine that the answer was so simple)

Comment: @swayn the question is had you checked the documentation? ;)